# rwd home page not responding to local.xml

Tags: theme, rwd

I'm using rwd package. I've done everything, created my own package, file structure, disabled cache, etc. When I go to change Madison Island home page from 1 column to 2 columns-left from local.xml, i.e.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <layout version="0.1.0">
     <default>
       <reference name="root">
         <action method="setTemplate">
           <template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template>
         </action>
       </reference>
     <default>
  </layout>
```

no alteration takes place to layout of home page. I can alter it from CMS -> pages. Any reason for this, have I missed anything in my local.xml? The reason I ask is if in future if I want to do any alteration to store via local.xml it might not be possible.

Answer (score 2):

I think the problem here is, you rely on `default` layout update handle and that change is overwritten by other layout update handle which has more priority over `default` layout update handle. (ex : `cms_page`, `cms_index_index` etc).

So just try this :

```
  <?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <layout version="0.1.0">
     <cms_index_index>
       <reference name="root">
         <action method="setTemplate">
           <template>page/2columns-left.phtml</template>
         </action>
       </reference>
     <cms_index_index>
  </layout>
```

Here `cms_index_index` is the action layout update handle. ie which is a special layout update handle which will be taken into consideration when Magento loads Home page. Also it has higher priority over other layout update handle.

---

<sup>**Note :** If you set any other layout update handles via admin side, then it would have the highest priority. In that case, layout update xml file changes are not going to work.</sup>

Comment: also best to use the update handle when setting core magento template such as the 2columns-left `<update handle="page_two_columns_left" />`

Comment: @rob3000 that is also correct. :)